# JS rotation function outputting weird X value

Tags: javascript, rotation, cartesian-coordinates

Hey i've made a rotation function in Javascript for rotating some 2D vector(point).

The Y output of the function works as expected, however the X value is outputting some crazy number, can anyone point out the floor in my logic?

```
Vector2.prototype.rotate = function(degrees){

    var angle = degrees * TO_RADIANS; //Convert to radians.
    var x =  (this.getX() * Math.cos(angle)) - (this.getY() * Math.sin(angle));
    var y = (this.getX() * Math.sin(angle)) + (this.getY() * Math.cos(angle));
    return new Vector2(x,y);
};
```

Inputting Vector(1,0) into this function with a rotation of 90 degrees outputs 6.someDecimalPlaces e-17; which is obviously incorrect.

The outputted Y value however works as expected and returns 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 6e-17 is pretty much zero. This should be the result of using floating point arithmetic.

Comment: You could improve the performance of your rotation if you calculate sin and cos only once. Probably not an issue but it might be significant if the rotation gets called very often.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! Math head clearly stayed in bed this morning lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "6.someDecimalPlaces e-17" you're seeing is due to Javascript's handling of floating point numbers.  What you're seeing is a rounding error in converting back from binary floating point to decimal.  There's no easy fix for this although there are libraries that attempt to overcome the problem.

If you want rounded numbers for pixel perfect CSS manupilation you're best bet is to round the numbers coming out of this function or cast them to integer.

Comment: Haha thanks, early morning coding for you there lol. Didn't even think to associate the value with 0. Cheers!